# How to stop multithreading returning combined data using python

Tags: python, multithreading, csv

When using a multithreading, I get combined data
The list is : A,B,C.  If I MT this, the fdata [] contains data from A,B and C. How do I Get fdata too hold only one set of data. I tried del fdata didnt help. I need some kind of lock.

```
class WorkerThread(threading.Thread):
       def __init__(self, queue):
            threading.Thread.__init__(self)
            self.queue = queue

       def run(self):
            while 1:
              try: # take a job from the queue
                   symbol, test, test2 = self.queue.get_nowait()

              except Queue.Empty:
                   raise SystemExit

              fn = %s.CSV" % symbol
              fdata = []
              fo = open(fn, 'rb')
              fr = csv.reader(fo, dialect='excel')
              for row in fr:
                   fdata.append(row)
              #print fdata 
              #del fdata
```

How would I add the thread number to fdata or list id A,B,C to fdata?

Comment: What exactly is multi threaded here? Is your fdata global in some way?

Answer (score 1):

fdata should always contain the contents of the CSV file, after all you did for-loop over the rows, so it should always include A B and C... Maybe you should explain more of what you're trying to do.

As to your second question -
Your thread object has an [ident](http://docs.python.org/library/thread.html#thread.get_ident) see `thread.get_ident()`

> Return the ‘thread identifier’ of the
>   current thread. This is a nonzero
>   integer. Its value has no direct
>   meaning; it is intended as a magic
>   cookie to be used e.g. to index a
>   dictionary of thread-specific data.
>   Thread identifiers may be recycled
>   when a thread exits and another thread
>   is created.

Edit:

Maybe fdata is somehow a global variable or being saved across accesses to the file? I see nothing in the code snippet that would do that, but I'm at a loss to otherwise explain it. According to the function fdata should be a locally scoped variable in the function, and it should just go away with the stack frame...

Comment: Trying do to: simple have a lot of csv's. all are pretty much the same. symbol.csv is file name. "symbol" changes. I want to multithread: the file read then load into db. I need fdata to contain onlt data from one file. As it stands now, fdata being open and used by all threads its being loaded all subquent csv data.